# Retrieving data using $http.post

Tags: angularjs, http

Hi I want to get data from my json file using post method(which is working 5n with get method)

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('myapp').controller('lastWeekWinners',function($http){
    var vm= this;
    $http.post('http://localhost:9000/json/sample.json').then(function(data){
        vm.winnerData=data.data.data;
    },function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

the about code is give error

[image]

which means can't we use post method to get the data

Comment: Read it first: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Don't use $http calls in controllers, use services for such matter.

Comment: does your API doesn't support POST? it is giving 404 error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the difference between GET/POST:

GET is used for getting data, POST is used for saving (and sometimes updating) data. So if you just want to get the json, use GET.

Regarding the specific problem you have here, if you look carefully, you get a 404 code. that means the route was not found. (You can read more about HTTP status code here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Not sure what server you're using but usually, you're not only defining a route but also the verb of the route (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE), so if you have a route defined like:

> GET /users/

This will only work for GET requests, if you try to post for the same route you'll get 404. You have to define the same route for the POST verb.

You can read more about http verbs here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how u can use the post method in your controller:

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('myapp').controller('lastWeekWinners', controller){

function controller($scope,fetch){
  var vm= this;
  vm.show = show;
}
function show() {

      return fetch.show()
       .then(function successCallback(data){         

          vm.winnerData = data; 
        }   
      }, function errorCallback (response) {
          console.log(response.statusText);
      }); 
  }

});
```

and in your service :

```
angular
    .module('service',[])
    .service('fetch', Service);
function Service($http) {
    var fetch = {      
        show : show
    }
    return fetch;
     function show() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:9000/json/sample.json')
        .then(getShowComplete)
        .catch(getShowFailed);

        function getShowComplete(response){ 
           return response.data;
        }
        function getShowFailed(error){
           console.log("Error:" + error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've give data:' ' ,because it is just a json file I want to get.

Comment: use an angular service and the Get Method if you want to GET Data!

Answer (score 0):

To do `$http.post` you need a back end API(PHP,Node Js etc),that system catch your desired post data and save into the db or JSON(Read/Write Method). 
Static JSON data just read only possible not write.

Or used Browser `$window.localStorage` to save data.